# Elasticsearch: get exact match, then fuzzy

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I run this query:

```
GET /thing/_search/?
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "castle pontivy",
      "type":       "most_fields",
      "fields":     [ "title", "loc" ]
    }
  }
}
```

It works and returns results from `thing` where `title` and `loc` contains `castle` and/or `pontivy` in a relevant order. Nice.

Now I want to continue querying like this, but I also want the result to prefer exact match on `title`. Which means that if one item exactly match `castle pontivy` in its title, it must be returned as first element (then the other results are treated as usual).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a `phrase` match and give it a `boost` of 5, so whatever the default score is, it will add +5 to that. If you want to get more into scoring, look into [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) (I recommend you should)

Second multi_match will match the rest of the documents using `most_fields`.

```
{  
  "query":{  
    "bool":{  
      "should":[  
        {  
          "multi_match":{  
            "query":"castle pontivy",
            "type":"phrase",
            "fields":[  
              "title",
              "loc"
            ],
            "boost":5
          }
        },
        {  
          "multi_match":{  
            "query":"castle pontivy",
            "type":"most_fields",
            "fields":[  
              "title",
              "loc"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can we add fuzziness in this?